# Kitty Terminal Hotkey Drop-Down/Overlay Hotkey (similar to iTerm2 hotkey window)

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, iterm2, kitty

##### TDLR

How to get something similar to the iTerm "dropdown hotkey/overlay" functionality to work with Kitty Terminal (on a Mac)?

---

I work on a Mac and used `iTerm2` for a long time and integrated the "hotkey window" into my workflow. Since I've made the switch to `Kitty` I have been trying to get the same functionality but couldn't find something that suits my needs.

#### **Caveat/Problems**

The one app that has this built-in, that I know of, is also `iTerm`. There's one big difference with this implementation and the native `iTerm` implementation.

`iTerm` is more of a "drop-down", in that it functions as an overlay. The `BTT` implementation will literally show and hide the application. This means that whenever you are working with multiple *desktops*, and you trigger this shortcut, *BTT* will move you to the *desktop* where the application is.

A similar solution for *Lunix* is using [tdrop](https://github.com/noctuid/tdrop). As far as I know there's no equivalent tool for MacOS

I find this quite annoying TBH and would love to know if anyone knows how to do the same thing, but in a "drop-down" or "overlay" fashion

#### **What I've tried**

##### BetterTouchTool **(BTT)**

This is the way I've set it up using BTT.
[image: BTT Config]

##### AppleScript

This does sort of the same thing, but without the use of BTT.

```applescript
set appName to "kitty"

tell application "System Events"
    if visible of application process appName is true then
        set visible of application process appName to false
    else
        set visible of application process appName to true
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the same concern and implemented with the help of [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/) app.

1. Firstly, we need tweak Kitty config in `~/.config/kitty/kitty.conf`:

```
# hide title and corners on Mac OS X
hide_window_decorations titlebar-and-corners
# make kitty app quit instead of empty window, which made the script hard to detect kitty status
macos_quit_when_last_window_closed yes
# this one is optional, this would save the script to move the terminal window to top if manually set
remember_window_size  yes
```

2. Secondly, copy below `init.lua` to `~/.hammerspoon`:

```lua
local spaces = require("hs.spaces") -- https://github.com/asmagill/hs._asm.spaces

-- Switch kitty
hs.hotkey.bind({'command'}, 'escape', function ()  -- hotkey config
  local BUNDLE_ID = 'net.kovidgoyal.kitty' -- more accurate to avoid mismatching on browser titles

  function getMainWindow(app)
    -- get main window from app
    local win = nil
    while win == nil do
      win = app:mainWindow()
    end
    return win
  end

  function moveWindow(kitty, space, mainScreen)
    -- move to main space
    local win = getMainWindow(kitty)
    if win:isFullScreen() then
      hs.eventtap.keyStroke('fn', 'f', 0, kitty)
    end
    winFrame = win:frame()
    scrFrame = mainScreen:fullFrame()
    winFrame.w = scrFrame.w
    winFrame.y = scrFrame.y
    winFrame.x = scrFrame.x
    win:setFrame(winFrame, 0)
    spaces.moveWindowToSpace(win, space)
    if win:isFullScreen() then
      hs.eventtap.keyStroke('fn', 'f', 0, kitty)
    end
    win:focus()
  end

  local kitty = hs.application.get(BUNDLE_ID)
  if kitty ~= nil and kitty:isFrontmost() then
    kitty:hide()
  else
    local space = spaces.activeSpaceOnScreen()
    local mainScreen = hs.screen.mainScreen()
    if kitty == nil and hs.application.launchOrFocusByBundleID(BUNDLE_ID) then
      local appWatcher = nil
      appWatcher = hs.application.watcher.new(function(name, event, app)
        if event == hs.application.watcher.launched and app:bundleID() == BUNDLE_ID then
          getMainWindow(app):move(hs.geometry({x=0,y=0,w=1,h=0.4}))
          app:hide()
          moveWindow(app, space, mainScreen)
          appWatcher:stop()
        end
      end)
      appWatcher:start()
    end
    if kitty ~= nil then
      moveWindow(kitty, space, mainScreen)
    end
  end
end)
```

Reload config in Hammerspoon, now you could invoke/launch Kitty with hotkey `cmd`+`esc`

Comment: I created a gist here: https://gist.github.com/truebit/d79b8018666d65e95970f208d8f5d149

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing! I will try this right now! Is changing the keybinding  to Option+Space as easy as doing `.bind({'option'}, 'space,`?

Comment: It's working flawlessly! I can't express how grateful I am for this solution. I've dedicated days to troubleshooting various approaches, and I'm still wondering how I missed discovering Hammerspoon.

Comment: @Y.Gherbi You are welcome. I searched github for the Alacritty workaround (https://gist.github.com/truebit/31396bb2f48c75285d724c9e9e037bcd) originally, adapted with the new Hammerspoon spaces module; but Alacritty not supporting multi-tab feature, in the end I ported it to Kitty then;)

Answer (score 2):

I feel your pain.

I achieved something I'm mostly happy with using yabai, skhd, bash, and several late nights.

I can try to describe more, buy my fugly script with several false starts is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Kitty Console command

# Ideal requirements:
# - If kitty is running:
#   - If there is no console window
#     - Create the console window, bring it to focus
#   - If there is a console window
#     - If it is not in focus or hidden, bring it to focus
#     - If it is in focus, hide the console window
# Bonus:
# - If kitty is not running:
#   - Launch kitty, create the console window, bring it to focus


# If a logfile is specified, it will write information there
logfile="${HOME}/.config/skhd/kitty_console.log"

function kclog {
    [[ -n "${logfile}" ]] && printf -- "$*\n" &>> "${logfile}"
}

kclog 'Launching Kitty Console Script.'
kclog "Which kitty = $(which kitty)"

function minimal_prototype {
    SOCKET='unix:/tmp/kitty-gui'
    kitty_cmd="kitty @ --to ${SOCKET}"

    # Save the below, this works well
    # 1) If kitty is not running, reports in log
    # 2) If kitty running and no Console window exists, creates one
    # 3) If kitty running and Console window exists, bring it to focus
    # Note that this requires the following in
    # ~/.config/kitty/macos-launch-services-cmd-line:
    # --override allow_remote_control=yes
    # --listen-on unix:/tmp/kitty-gui

    ${kitty_cmd} focus-window --match title:Console \
        || ${kitty_cmd} new-window --window-type os --title Console \
        || { \
            printf 'Kitty likely not running, launching \n' > "${logfile}";
            kitty --single-instance --directory "${HOME}" --override allow_remote_control=yes --listen-on "${SOCKET}"  --title Console; \
        }
}

function minimal_prototype_2 {
    SOCKET='unix:/tmp/kitty-gui'
    kitty_cmd="kitty @ --to ${SOCKET}"

    # Save the below, this works well
    # 1) If kitty is not running, reports in log and launches kitty normally,
    #    then launches console window
    # 2) If kitty running and no Console window exists, creates one
    # 3) If kitty running and Console window exists, bring it to focus
    # Note that this requires the following in
    # ~/.config/kitty/macos-launch-services-cmd-line:
    # --override allow_remote_control=yes
    # --listen-on unix:/tmp/kitty-gui

    ${kitty_cmd} focus-window --match title:Console \
        || ${kitty_cmd} new-window --window-type os --title Console \
        || { \
            printf 'Kitty likely not running, launching \n' > "${logfile}";
            /Applications/kitty.app/Contents/MacOS/kitty  --single-instance --directory "${HOME}" --override allow_remote_control=yes --listen-on "${SOCKET}" & \
            sleep 1; \
            ${kitty_cmd} new-window --window-type os --title Console; \
        }
}

function minimal_prototype_3 {
    SOCKET='unix:/tmp/kitty-console'
    kitty_cmd="kitty @ --to ${SOCKET}"
    # This version launches a separate kitty instance for console

    # Save the below, this works well
    # 1) If kitty is not running, reports in log and launches kitty normally,
    #    then launches console window
    # 2) If kitty running and no Console window exists, creates one
    # 3) If kitty running and Console window exists, bring it to focus
    # Note that this requires the following in
    # ~/.config/kitty/macos-launch-services-cmd-line:
    # --override allow_remote_control=yes
    # --listen-on unix:/tmp/kitty-gui

    ${kitty_cmd} focus-window --match title:Console \
        || ${kitty_cmd} new-window --window-type os --title Console \
        || { \
            printf 'Kitty likely not running, launching \n' > "${logfile}";
            kitty --directory "${HOME}" --override macos_hide_from_tasks=yes --override allow_remote_control=yes --listen-on "${SOCKET}" & \
            sleep 1; \
            ${kitty_cmd} new-window --window-type os --title Console; \
        }
    yabai -m rule --add app=kitty title=Console sticky=on
}


function simple_kitty_console {
    # This function implements a simple console window.
    SOCKET='unix:/tmp/kitty-gui'
    kitty_cmd="kitty @ --to ${SOCKET}"
    if ${kitty_cmd} focus-window --match title:Console; then
        kclog 'Focusing Console window'
    else
        kclog 'No Console window, create.'
        ${kitty_cmd} new-window --window-type os --title Console \
            && yabai -m rule --add \
                label=kitty-console \
                app=kitty \
                title=Console \
                sticky=on \
                grid=1:2:2:1:1:1 \
                manage=on
    fi
}

function hide_process {
    osascript -e "
        tell application \"System Events\"
            set visible of the first process whose unix id is ${1} to false
        end tell
    "
}

function show_process {
    osascript -e "
        tell application \"System Events\"
            set visible of the first process whose unix id is ${1} to true
        end tell
    "

}

function activate_process {
    # Assumes that variable `myProcessId` contains the PID of interest.
    osascript -e "
        tell application \"System Events\"
            set frontmost of the first process whose unix id is ${1} to true
        end tell
        "
}

function independent_kitty_console {
    # This function launches an independent kitty instance
    # This function implements a simple console window.
    SOCKET='unix:/tmp/kitty-console'
    kitty_cmd="kitty @ --to ${SOCKET}"
    # if ${kitty_cmd} focus-window --match title:Console; then
    if ${kitty_cmd} focus-window; then
        kclog 'Focusing Console window'
    else
        kclog 'No Console window, create.'
        launch_new_hidden_kitty
        # ${kitty_cmd} new-window --window-type os --title Console \
        #     && yabai -m rule --add \
        #         label=kitty-console \
        #         app=kitty \
        #         title=Console \
        #         sticky=on \
        #         grid=1:2:2:1:1:1 \
        #         manage=on
    fi
    :
}

function launch_new_kitty {
    SOCKET='unix:/tmp/kitty-console'
    { kitty --title Console --directory '/' --listen-on "${SOCKET}" & } 2>/dev/null
    kitty_pid=$!
    disown -r "${kitty_pid}"
    printf "${kitty_pid}\n"
}

function launch_new_hidden_kitty {
    # This works well to launch a hidden instance of Kitty and get the PID, but
    # it seems that kitty windows launched in this way do not respond the same
    # way to the Apple events the way 'non-hidden' Kitty windows do.
    SOCKET='unix:/tmp/kitty-console'
    { kitty --title Console --override macos_hide_from_tasks=yes --directory '/' --listen-on "${SOCKET}" & } 2>/dev/null
    kitty_pid=$!
    disown -r "${kitty_pid}"

    kclog "${kitty_pid}"
    # Attempt to rename the window on launch
    kitty @ --to "${SOCKET}" set-window-title -m recent:0 Console
}

function learnings {
    # Get the process ID of the bash instance inside kitty window
    kitty @ --to unix:/tmp/kitty-console ls | jq '.[].tabs[].windows[].pid'

    # From this, one can use
    ps -f $KITTY_BASH_PID

    # To get the main kitty PID
}

function kitty_console_post_fix {
    # This is work performed after I saw the following fix:
    # https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/issues/5210
    # This function implements a simple console window.
    # This uses the "launch" command
    SOCKET='unix:/tmp/kitty-gui'
    kitty_cmd="kitty @ --to ${SOCKET}"
    if ${kitty_cmd} focus-window --match title:Console; then
        kclog 'Focusing Console window'
    else
        kclog 'No Console window, create.'
        ${kitty_cmd} launch --type=os-window --title=Console \
            && yabai -m rule --add \
                label=kitty-console \
                app=kitty \
                title=Console \
                sticky=on \
                grid=1:2:2:1:1:1 \
                manage=on
    fi


}

function independent_kitty_console_post_fix {
    kclog '\nRunning independent_kitty_console_post_fix'
    # This function launches an independent kitty instance
    # This function implements a simple console window.
    SOCKET='unix:/tmp/kitty-console'
    kitty_cmd="kitty @ --to ${SOCKET}"
    if ${kitty_cmd} focus-window --match title:Console; then
        kclog 'Focusing Console window'
    else
        launch_new_hidden_kitty
        # if ${kitty_cmd} launch --type=os-window --title=Console \
        #     --override macos_hide_from_tasks=yes; then
        #     kclog 'No Console window, create.'
        #     yabai -m rule --add \
        #         label=kitty-console \
        #         app=kitty \
        #         title=Console \
        #         sticky=on \
        #         grid=1:2:2:1:1:1 \
        #         manage=on
        # else
        #     kclog 'No Kitty instance, launching'
        #     { kitty --override macos_hide_from_tasks=yes --directory '/' --listen-on "${SOCKET}" & } 2>/dev/null
        #     kitty_pid=$!
        #     disown -r "${kitty_pid}"
        #     kclog "${kitty_pid}\n"
        # ${kitty_cmd} launch --type=os-window --title=Console \
        #     && yabai -m rule --add \
        #         label=kitty-console \
        #         app=kitty \
        #         title=Console \
        #         sticky=on \
        #         manage=on
        #         # grid=1:2:2:1:1:1 \
        # fi
    fi
}

# simple_kitty_console
# independent_kitty_console
# kitty_console_post_fix
# independent_kitty_console_post_fix


################################################################################
# Another try - 2022-09-12
################################################################################
# This tries to achieve my goal using a separate instance of kitty for the
# Console window. Codename: ibk (itty bitty kitty)

IBK_SOCKET='unix:/tmp/kitty-console'

function ibk_launch {
    # Launch a Console instance of Kitty
    # Note: I launch it using the root directory as an extra way of identifying
    # which instance is the Console instance.
    kitty \
        --title Console \
        --directory "${HOME}" \
        --override allow_remote_control=yes \
        --listen-on "${IBK_SOCKET}"
}

function ibk_launch_background {
    # Launch a Console instance of Kitty
    # Note: I launch it using the root directory as an extra way of identifying
    # which instance is the Console instance.
    { kitty \
        --title Console \
        --directory "${HOME}" \
        --override allow_remote_control=yes \
        --listen-on "${IBK_SOCKET}" &
    } &> /dev/null
    kitty_pid=$!
    disown -r "${kitty_pid}"
    # yabai -m rule --add \
    #     label=kitty-console \
    #     app=kitty \
    #     title=Console \
    #     sticky=on
    # echo -n "${kitty_pid}"
}

function ibk_get_pid {
    # Get the pid of the kitty process in order to hide it
    # local ppids
    # ppids=$(
    # Note: if kitty ls returns '[]', no windows exist
    _ppids="$( \
        kitty @ --to "${IBK_SOCKET}" ls \
            | jq '.[].tabs[].windows[].pid' \
            | xargs -I {} ps -o ppid= {} \
            | sort \
            | uniq
    )"
    num_ppids=$(echo "$_ppids" | wc -l)
    if [[ "${num_ppids// /}" == '1' && -n "${_ppids}" ]]; then
        echo -n "${_ppids}"
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

function ibk_hide {
    hide_process "$(ibk_get_pid)"
}

function ibk_show {
    show_process "$(ibk_get_pid)"
}

function ibk_focus {
    activate_process "$(ibk_get_pid)"
}

function ibk_is_hidden {
    # I'm not sure how to do this yet, but I'll need to check whether or not
    # the instance of kitty is hidden.
    :
}

function ibk_toggle {
    osascript -e "
        tell application \"System Events\"
            if frontmost of the first process whose unix id is ${1} then
                set visible of the first process whose unix id is ${1} to false
            else
                set frontmost of the first process whose unix id is ${1} to true
            end if
        end tell
        "
}


function ibk_kitty_console {
    # Todo: Add ability to hide if currently in focus with same function
    if ibk_pid=$(ibk_get_pid) &> /dev/null; then
        ibk_toggle "${ibk_pid}"
        # ibk_focus "${ibk_pid}"
    else
        # Either not running, or has no windows open
        if [[ '[]' == "$(kitty @ --to "${IBK_SOCKET}" ls)" ]]; then
            # Running, but has no windows open, create one
            kitty @ --to "${IBK_SOCKET}" launch --type=os-window
        else
            # Not running, launch
            ibk_launch_background
        fi
    fi
    ibk_ensure_yabai_managed
}

function ibk_ensure_yabai_managed {
    yabai -m rule --list | grep -q '"label":"kitty-console"' || \
        yabai -m rule --add \
            label=kitty-console \
            app=kitty \
            title=Console \
            sticky=on
}

ibk_kitty_console
```

I use shkd to run it using Ctrl-~ via:

```
ctrl - 0x32 : ~/.config/skhd/kitty_console
```

Comment: I'll definitely try this and let you know if it works for me. Thanks a lot! I do feel like using yabai/skhd is a pretty big change in my workflow, but I already invested too much time into this to leave it for what it is haha, I appreciate it!

Comment: I also awarded the 50 points to this answer

Comment: Thank you for this. I am goign to try to adapt it to work with WezTerm.